# Website project not including files in the underlying directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to work on ASP.NET Website project. I have one specific git branch that behaves really weirdly. When I switch to that branch, some of the files (the ones that exist in that branch only for now) are not appearing in Solution Explorer, they are not included in the build process as well
[image]

For a workaround I am using "Add existing files" to bring files back, but there are no changes for me to commit since there is no .csproj file to track which files are within projects. Once I add files, everything works as expected, but it is so annoying to do same thing over and over. How do I fix that?

Update:

Now I have reversed behavior, file is displayed in the branch it never existed in. When I click "Show history", empty page appears.

[image]

`git ls-files` does not show any file

[image]

Comment: Can it be that a `.gitignore` rule is ignoring your files? You may verify by using the command: `git check-ignore -v -- path/to/your/ignored/file`.

Comment: @harrymc not sure if it is a git issue, now I have slightly different issue and git says it is innocent. posted an update